# Reference stored procedure in another database?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

From a stored procedure or function in a given MySQL database, is it possible to reference a stored procedure or function in another MySQL database, as follows?

```
SELECT 
    some_table.field1,
    some_table.field2,
    another_database.STORED_PROCEDURE(arg), 
    ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

Comment: -1 This is something very easy to find on your own!

Comment: I asked because I am working with someone else's code, I have never written a stored procedure, and it was 3x faster for me to ask a question and get a response in five minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, just prefix them with the database name.

BTW: What you're showing is a stored function. For stored procedures you must use CALL and they can't return a value.